# Android Wear Bluetooth RFCOMM API

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, wear-os

Today I started working on connection of Android Wear with Universal Windows Platform(focused on Windows Phone mostly). The main purpose is to send notifications from my app to watch and control music on phone from it. Since there isn't any solution to this problem on the internet, I have only 6-second video on reddit of a Lumia 950 sending notification using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm to smartwatch.
Is there any API of Bluetooth services by smartwatches? So I could simply create a socket at least from phone to watch? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-wear/iElNBQ4rZzQ) : Android wear does not currently support Windows Phone Operating system. You might want to check if your device is compatible to [pair with Android Wear](https://www.android.com/wear/check/). But to answer your "Is there any API to send notifications from my app to watch and control music on phone from it", Yes there is. You might want to read about the documentation - [Sending and Syncing Data](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html):

> The Wearable Data Layer API, which is part of Google Play services, provides a communication channel for your handheld and wearable apps. The API consists of a set of data objects that the system can send and synchronize over the wire and listeners that notify your apps of important events with the data layer.

Here is a useful [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/02/building-for-android-wear-depth-and.html) that talks about the capabilities of Android Wear and Media playback controls [`MediaSession`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html?utm_campaign=building-for-wear-215&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog), [`MediaController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.html?utm_campaign=building-for-wear-215&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog).

Hope this helps.